# Interpretation in Ebbinghaus's Mathematical Logic

Tags: logic

In Ebbinghaus, Flum, Thomas' Mathematical Logic, second edition, page 30:

> For example, if $S = S^{<}_{\text{ar}}$, and the interpretation $\mathfrak{I} = (\mathfrak{A}, \beta)$ is given by
>   $$
>   \mathfrak{A} = (\mathbf{N}, +, \cdot, 0, 1, <)
>   \quad\text{and}\quad
>   \text{$\beta(v_n) = 2n$ for $n \geq 0$}
> $$
>   then the formula $v_2 \cdot (v_1 + v_2) \equiv v_4$ (actually ${} \cdot v_2 + v_1 v_2 \equiv v_4$) reads “$4 \cdot (2 + 4) = 8$”, and the formula $\forall v_0 \exists v_1 v_0 < v_1$ (actually: $\forall v_0 \exists v_1 < v_0 v_1$) reads “for every natural number there is a larger natural number.”
>
> ([Original scan here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QvUy.png).)

$v_n$ was interpreted as $2n$ for $n \geq 0$. So I would expect "$\forall v_0 \exists v_1 v_0 < v_1$" to be interpreted as "for all 0, there exists 2 such that 0<2". But it was interpreted as "for every natural number there is a larger natural number" in the book.

Does this mean that in the presence of quantifiers, the (bound?) variables should not be interpreted but be used as free variables?

Comment: Indeed, bounded variables are not interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the interpretation of $\forall v_0, \varphi(v_0)$ is that it holds in the model $(M,\beta)$ if for all ways of changing $\beta$ on $v_0$ (while keeping the rest fixed) into $\tilde{\beta}$, then $(M,\tilde{\beta})\models \varphi(v_0)$; otherwise quantifiers would be useless (since you fixed a $\beta$ !)